# QObject::connect: signal not found (in subclass)

Tags: c++, qt

I've managed to boil down my app's problem to a small sample.

I'm unable to connect a signal defined in a base class.

Here's my simple wtf.pro file:

```
QT += widgets
SOURCES = wtf.cpp TableViewSubclass.cpp
HEADERS = TableViewSubclass.h
```

Here's my TableViewSubclass.h:

```
#include <QTableView>

class TableViewSubclass : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TableViewSubclass(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QTableView(parent) {}
    virtual ~TableViewSubclass() {}

    void setup();

private slots:
    void viewColumnCountChanged(int oldcount, int newcount);
};
```

Here's my TableViewSubclass.cpp. For good measure, I tried two ways to connect the signal to the slot.

```
#include "TableViewSubclass.h"

void
TableViewSubclass::setup()
{
    // Trying to use &QTableView::columnCountChanged for parameter 2
    // gives me a compiler error, for being protected within this context.
    QObject::connect(this, &TableViewSubclass::columnCountChanged,
        this, &TableViewSubclass::viewColumnCountChanged);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(columnCountChanged(int,int)),
        this, SLOT(viewColumnCountChanged(int,int)));
}

void
TableViewSubclass::viewColumnCountChanged(int /* oldcount */, int /* newcount */)
{
    // TODO
}
```

And finally, the main wtf.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "TableViewSubclass.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TableViewSubclass oView;
    oView.setup();
}
```

I build with `qmake-qt5 wtf.pro` and `make`, then run with `./wtf`. It outputs:

```
QObject::connect: signal not found in TableViewSubclass
QObject::connect: No such signal TableViewSubclass::columnCountChanged(int,int)
```

The signal is defined in `QTableView`, the base class for `TableViewSubclass`. How is it not found? It seems like I'm missing something obvious and stupid.

The above example was run under Fedora Core 35 and Qt 5.15.2, but was first encountered in MinGW, also with Qt 5.15.2.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @G.M. : I'm trying to detect when the view has finished creating columns based on details received from the newly-set model. (I need to perform some post-population setup on the view.) So far, the only method I've found is to override `updateGeometries()` in my `QTableView` subclass, which seems unstable to me...it works, but only because of how the Qt code is implemented presently. I tried connecting to `QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged` and `QAbstractItemModel::columnsInserted` but neither signal fires.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#columnCountChanged), the `countColumnChanged(int, int)` is a slot and not a signal.
You can override this protected slot in your derived class:

```
#include <QTableView>

class TableViewSubclass : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TableViewSubclass(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QTableView(parent) {}
    virtual ~TableViewSubclass() {}

    void setup();

protected slots:
    void columnCountChanged(int oldcount, int newcount) override;
};
```

The slot is called by the base class (QTableView) each time the column count changes. Therefore, there is no need to connect any signal to this slot to update the behavior in your derived class.

Comment: No, wait...`columnCountChanged` isn't virtual, so trying to override it fails. That brings up the question of the purpose of a protected slot at all.

Comment: @ulatekh I suspect these protected slots are used to be connected to the corresponding model of the view. They have to be slots (to be connectable to signals) but they are intended for internal use only. Hence, a `protected slot`.

Comment: columnCountChanged() is connected to the signal horizontalHeader::sectionCountChanged() and this is emitted when the model emits columnsInserted() or columnsRemoved() which is the signal where you connect your slot on.